# where to change responsive media breakpoint 767px in magento 2

Tags: navigation, magento2.4, mobile-menu, mobile-device

I am working on responsive navigation menu in magento 2.4 version.
When I set width 768px in a browser it changes layout to desktop view. So I wanna keep this responsive menu design  till 1024px which and where I have to change the code to achieve this ?
I changed the code from `767px` to `1024px` in `lib\web\mage\menu.js` and `pub\static\frontend\Magento\luma\en_US\mage\menu.js` line number 25

```
mediaBreakpoint: '(max-width: 1024px)'
```

but nothing happened. So where I have to change the code to make responsive menu till width `1024px`

Comment: @RakeshDonga your code where should I put ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. The media attribute for the styles-l.css stylesheet**

*In the default_head_blocks.xml file of your theme change the breakpoint used for loading the styles-l.css stylesheet to 1024px.*

***app/design/frontend/[Theme namespace]/[theme name]/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml***

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <head>
        <css src="css/styles-l.css" media="screen and (min-width: 1025px)"/>
    </head>
</page>
```

**2. The @screen__m LESS Breakpoint**

*You can change the value for @screen__m in your theme’s _variables.less.
Copy this file from your parent theme to your theme, if you haven’t done so already, and add:*

***app/design/frontend/[Theme namespace]/[theme name]/web/css/source/_variables.less***

```
// Overriding values for core breakpoints
@screen__m: 1025px;
```

**3. Breakpoint in menu.js**

*In your theme create a requirejs-config.js file.*

***app/design/frontend/[Theme namespace]/[theme name]/requirejs-config.js***

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'mage/menu': {
                'Magento_Theme/js/menu-media-breakpoint-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

*Next add the JavaScript mixin file to change the breakpoint to 1024px.*

***app/design/frontend/[Theme namespace]/[theme name]/Magento_Theme/web/js/menu-media-breakpoint-mixin.js***

```
define([], function () {
    'use strict';

    return function (widget) {
        widget.menu.prototype.options.mediaBreakpoint = '(max-width: 1024px)';

        return widget;
    };
});
```

**4. Breakpoint in responsive.js**

**Unfortunately for responsive.js, the file needs to be overridden rather than extended in the theme.**

*A JavaScript mixin won’t work as it is initialised in the deps block of the blank parent theme’s requirejs-config file rather than within the define parameters of a requirejs module, a data-mage-init attribute or the  tag.*

*So copy*

**vendor/magento/theme-frontend-blank/Magento_Theme/web/js/responsive.js**

**(some times found in the vendor/ directory depending on how you installed Magento)**

*to your theme’s*

```
app/design/frontend/[Theme namespace]/[theme name]/Magento_Theme/web/js/ directory.
```

***And in this file change:***

```
media: '(min-width: 768px)'
```

*to*

```
media: '(min-width: 1025px)'
```

Comment: thanks for your input,let me check with your code

Comment: @NirajPatel Solved ?

Comment: Thanks I accepted answer